# Check if Element with ID has a value

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, twebbrowser

How to check if **"Some text value"** in element **p** with **Id = "SomeID"** is there?

```
<p id="SomeID" class="error" style="display: none"></p>

<p id="SomeID" class="error" style="display: none">Some text value</p>
```

Here it is in a function form..

```
function ElementIdText(Web:TembeddedWB; Id:string):string;
var
  node: string;
begin
  if Assigned(Web.Document) and web.DocumentLoaded then begin
  node:=Web.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID(Id).innerText;
  if not VarIsNull(Node) and not VarIsClear(Node) and not AnsiSameStr(node,'') then
  result:=node;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: About your update, I'm not sure since I couldn't duplicate the exact issue in your comment but, IMHO, I believe you'd better; Declare a temporary variant (e.g. 'element') and assign `Web.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID(Id)` to it, then check for `VarIsClear`, that would take care of an invalid 'ID'. Another temporary variant (e.g. 'text') and `text:=element.innerText`, and check for `VarIsNull` on 'text' before assigning to 'result'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```
<p id="SomeID" class="error" style="display: none"></p>
<p id="SomeOtherID" class="error" style="display: none">Some text value</p>
```

To retrieve an attribute, use:

```
ShowMessage(WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.
    GetElementByID('SomeOtherID').getAttribute('style').Display);
```

will output 'none'.

To get the text of the paragraph you can use this:

```
ShowMessage(WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.
    GetElementByID('SomeOtherID').innerText);
```

Comment: @Joey - I changed one of your 'ID's: SomeOtherID, maybe it's because of that?

Comment: Error is thrown if the text is not there but if it is it works. So likely it contains NULL but how to check if it contains it?

Comment: @Joey - With XE2 here, I get an empty text for a paragraph having no text. If the ID have been invalid you could check `VarIsClear` on a temporary variant that has been assigned to 'WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('SomeID')', if the temporary variant is null you can check `VarIsNull`, otherwise I don't know. The worst case, you can trap the error but not very elegant of course.

Comment: why should the first code return "none" if the attribute value is "display: none"? (Not knowing what '.Display' is doing)

Comment: @mjn - It's the display property of the style attribute, put 'block' in the source and it will retrieve 'block', put 'anything' and it will retrieve empty text. But frankly I'm not a DOM expert at all...